# Dynamic where clause using page item in interactive report does not work

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I simply created a interactive report based on the oracle table and set a `Hidden Page Item` called `P1_contrain_parameter` to receive the value passed from another page. The `P1_contrain_parameter` is used in the where clause as follow:

```
(Column_name = :P1_contrain_parameter)
```

But it does not work in this way. I tried to set the page item as `Display only` and found that the value has been successfully passed to the current report. I also tried to set the where clause as

```
(Column_name = 'actual_value')
```

It also works. However, it just do not what when I pass the `actual value` to `P1_contrain_parameter` to construct the dynamic where clause. Can anybody tell what might be wrong here?

Comment: Assuming that you haven't misspelled the parameter name (90% of the time, that's the mistake that I make), you'd probably need to enable debugging and step through the debug log to see what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for your reminding. I have checked the parameter name million times since that's also the mistake I always made. I'll try the debug mode.

Comment: Check that item is included in the "Page items to submit" region property.

Comment: "Page items to submit" shouldn't be a factor here since the value is being passed via URL syntax.

Comment: You said, "But it does not work in this way." What does this mean? Do you get no rows back? Do you get all the rows back (as though the filter doesn't work at all)?

Comment: Also, a better way to check session state is by clicking the Session link in the Developer Toolbar.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing expression. "Does not work" means I get no rows back.

Comment: Did you run the same in SQL Developer (direct copy) and it works?
How about in your SQL, remove the predicate and put the two columns side by side: `column_name, :p1_contrain_parameter column_name_2`. Are the equal?